# Auto Login Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm developing a web application with spring security, and I have to test some pages that are in the private area, and every time I have to login to test that page.

Is there a functionality that make spring security login automatically with a given user so I can test the pages direct?

Thanks

Comment: Use a recent spring security version and you can annotate a test with `@WithMockUser` etc. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-method.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
      public Authentication authenticateUserAndSetSession(String username,HttpServletRequest request){

          UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(username);

          Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, userDetails.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());

          SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

          request.getSession().setAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, SecurityContextHolder.getContext());

          return authentication;
      }
```

Use this method and pass only username and request object on this method. This is works for me. I think it's help you.

Comment: kudos for neat solution

Answer (score 0):

I assume the login page has something difficult to test with automated tools such as Selenium.

I had the same issue some time ago and came out with the solution to have two maven 
profiles one for production and another for testing. For testing the whole spring-security is turned off (by filtering spring xml files) and replaced it with the hardcoded default user profile.

This made it possible for Selenium to do not bother with captcha on login page.

Comment: Hi , you want to avoid this selenium solution then you can check my above answer.